# i3wm: Set window splitting sequence such that screen is divided into quadrants

Tags: i3

Is it possible to configure i3 to place new containers of a workspace in a certain way? I want the containers to be gradually oriented as in the below picture without having to manually split and move them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[nwg-piotr's autotiling script](https://github.com/nwg-piotr/autotiling) is what you want. It doesn't automatically place app #3 in the bottom left quadrant, since it splits the window based on the longest edge. However, if you look at the [YouTube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWRZuhn92bQ) you see it's possible to do what you want if you switch focus just once.